# Как загрузить проект на GitHub не из Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: github, visual-studio-2019

Возможно странный вопрос, но у меня заканчивается данный процесс еще на этапе попытки добавить нужное расширение... Как только открываю окно "Управление расширениями", студия намертво зависает :(

Я так же пробовал установить расширение GitHub через Visual Studio Installer, и вроде установил...
Но подключение к GitHub ни чего не дает...

Нужной команды "Add Solution to Source Control", при щелчке правой кнопкой мыши по решению не появляется..

Если перейти в раздел Git, то я не могу выбрать владельца, поэтому дальнейшие действия не возможны...

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле вариантов множество:

1)Насколько я понимаю вы работаете под Windows, поэтому можете скачать git-консоль отсюда https://git-scm.com/download/win, закомитить и запушить через команды git, если раньше не работали с инструментом git, то рекомендую почитать на этом же ресурсе документацию

2)Вы также можете загрузить проект прямо  в веб-интерфейсе гитхаб, для этого, когда переходите внутрь репозитория есть соответствующая кнопка:
[image: загрузка через веб-интерфейс]

Comment: Спасибо, а есть ли возможность создавать папки прямо в репозитории ? Хотелось бы загрузить проект в таком в виде, как он есть у меня в решении :)

Comment: Там есть возможность загрузить папку как она есть, при этом структура проекта сохранится

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать GitHub Desktop https://desktop.github.com/ .
Ну или просто Git.

Comment: Пробовал Git десктоп, я так понял, что он позволяет создать репозиторий, но не загружает сам проект. Или я плохо разобрался ?